# Fill remaining width with div, no set sizes

Tags: jquery, css

I've seen a couple of these questions but none that specifically seemed to work with my situation. I have a tabbed navigation that could flex in size based on the amount of tabs added to the navigation. I then have a second area with the phone number area that I would like to have fill the remaining area, stretching from the right to fill space to the left.

I don't know the width of either object. The closest solution I had to this was to float the nav left, which then had the blue area expand behind the nav, which wasn't what I was looking for as I wanted to still be able to see the background between the tab gaps. I tried tables, but couldn't get it to work. Either it would give the blue area only it's width and then give the nav the rest without filling the space in the middle, or in another configuration it would collapse the size of the containing table to the width of the 2 elements combined and not fill the full 960px width.

[image: Variable width fill]

Ideally I would love to find a CSS solution, but I'm not averse to JS or jQuery.

Comment: Show some `html` and `css` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your navigation tabs are floated, adding `overflow: hidden;` to the dark blue `div` (the one you want to take up remaining width) should be sufficient.

Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/6Cavr/).

Comment: I guess the bit I was missing was the overflow hidden. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `width: 100%` do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Working code on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yaw57/11/)

```
<div class="base">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="extra">
        Hello is nothing but Hello
    </div>
    <br clear="all"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.base{
   width:100%;
   background:#c00;
   color:#fff;
   padding-top:15px;    
}
.menu{
    float:left;
}
.menu ul li{
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    background:#000;
    padding:3px;
    border-radius:8px 8px 0px 0px;

}
.extra{
   float:right;
}
```